# Turing Reduction, Hilbert's 10th Problem

Tags: polynomials, computer-science, computability, turing-machines, hilbert-polynomial

I have the following problem :

Using the fact the following language is undecidable H: The set of all multivariate polynomial with integer coefficients `[p]` such that it evaluates to zero for some assignment of positive integers to its variable. Show that the language P: `<p,q>` the set of all pairs of multivariate polynomial  both with integer coefficients, such that for some assignment of integer values `p>q`.

I think I can prove this by showing that H is Turing reducible from P. But I can't find a way to use that fact that `p>q` to show `r=0`.
My approach was to try to bound `-1<r<1`. But if `-1<r<1` doesn't mean that `p=0` for some assignment. Help !

Thank you ~

Comment: I notice that H is defined in terms of positive integer solutions but P is defined in terms of arbitrary integers.  Is this distinction deliberate or is it a typo?

Comment: Also, it should say "H is Turing reducible *to* P". So if we had a machine for P, we would have a machine for H, a contradiction.

Comment: @ErickWong If the distinction is a typo the problem becomes completely different. If solutions are indeed restricted to be positive integers I'm pretty sure I know how to solve this. I will check back tomorrow to see if OP has replied.

Comment: @RenéG just checked, it is not a typo...

Comment: There are standard tricks for converting between "positive integer" and "integer" variables by adding more variables.  If $n_1$ and $n_2$ as natural, then $n_1-n_2$ can take any integer value.  The other direction is more interesting: if $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ are integers, then $1+z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2+z_4^2$ can take any positive integer value.  The latter construction requires much more background to prove so it seems odd for it to be needed at this level.

Comment: I suppose since we are dealing with polynomials we might be able to expand out both $p(n)$ and $p(1-n)$ out for each input variable, to cover both positive and no positive values?  Maybe with some clever way to exploit the inequality operator to eliminate false positives?

Comment: @ErickWong Using Lagrange's four square theorem is indeed a neat way to do this. The theorem is not that hard to prove... but I suppose it is indeed not the intended method. Probably then just a typo?